# How to convert Javascript array to JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array called values which has this data

```
var values=new Array();
values.push("english":"http://www.test.in/audio_ivrs/sr_listenglishMSTR001.wav");
values.push("kannada":"http://www.test.in/audio_ivrs/sr_listfrenchMSTR001.wav");
```

When I do JSON.stringify(values) I get values with square brackets, but I need a JSON string a shown below with urllist appended at the first.

```
{
   "urlList":{
      "english":"http://www.test.in/audio_ivrs/sr_listenglishMSTR001.wav",
      "kannada":"http://www.test.in/audio_ivrs/sr_listfrenchMSTR001.wav"
   }
}
```

Comment: That's not an array. http://json.org/

Answer (score 4):

Your code as you've defined it will give you errors. This is not valid JavaScript; you can't create an array element like this.

```
values.push("english":"http://www.test.in/audio_ivrs/sr_listenglishMSTR001.wav");
```

If you want the structure you've specified in your question then you'll need to use a nested object rather than an array to contain the key/value pairs.

```
var values = {
  urlList: {}
};

values.urllist.english = "http://www.test.in/audio_ivrs/sr_listenglishMSTR001.wav";
values.urllist.kannada = "http://www.test.in/audio_ivrs/sr_listfrenchMSTR001.wav";
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LJWGy/)

**HOWEVER...**

Let's assume for a moment that what you meant to code was this (note the curly braces):

```
var values=new Array();
values.push({"english":"http://www.test.in/audio_ivrs/sr_listenglishMSTR001.wav"});
values.push({"kannada":"http://www.test.in/audio_ivrs/sr_listfrenchMSTR001.wav"});
```

This would tell me that you're pushing *objects* into an array which is perfectly *valid* JavaScript.

To get this information from the array into the structure you need you can use something like this loop:

```
var out = {
    urlList: {}
};

for (var i = 0, l = values.length; i < l; i++) {
  var el = values[i];
  var key = Object.keys(el);
  var value = el[key];
  out.urlList[key] = value;
}

JSON.stringify(out);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ErYdZ/)

Comment: Well I copy this values from textfields using serialize array